# Problem converting images for beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics

I've got many troubles with raster images and `beamer` class:

1. convert `*.png` to `eps`, cslatex => dvips => ps2pdf, images look like compressed by jpg algorithm :/
2. convert `*.png` -> `eps` -> `pdf` (`epstopdf`) - images after conversion look like compressed again...
3. use `*.png` and `pdfcslatex` - images are ok, however positioning, etc. doesn't work good...
4. use `cslatex` => `dvipdfm` - doesn't work with beamerclass...

Without beamer, I'm using the 4th option with `eps` images and everything's ok... Beamer is really a great package, however these troubles with images are * * * * *

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other possibility?

**solved**

Comment: What is the original format of your images? PNG? If you are using PNG, you just need to use pdflatex.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the `beamer` *class* in particular. Images aren't included any different with it than any other LaTeX documents (Maybe you might know LaTeX only from `beamer`?). I would recommend you as well to use `pdflatex` and PNG images directly.

Comment: mics - some of them are `png`, others `eps`. Thus, I wanted to convert all of them to `eps`... Well, `pdflatex` is not the best options, due to strange spacing, centering, etc...

Comment: I probably find the problem with centering - I was using bb with pdf, and thus, it couldn't work. Ok, I hope, it's allright now

Comment: `pdflatex` shouldn't behave different for spacing, centering, etc. You are right that `bb` could caused problems with PDF images. There is no need to use this with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the biggest mistake I made was using of bb (I forgot to remove when I changed from png to pdf)  with pdf images. So, I am using pdflatex and it works now. Sorry for silly question...

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what the issue was. With `pdflatex` you don't need `bb` for PDF, PNG or JPG images. It can read the bounding box information directly from the files. Please accept this answer after the required waiting period (48 hours I think) so that the question is officially concluded. Thanks.